# mongoose populate method not working is there any other way to get data from another collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Following is my schema
Product.js

```
const Mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = Mongoose.Schema;
const { Types } = Schema;

const Product = new Schema(
  {
    productName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
    },
    productType: {
      type: Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
      required: true,
    },
    stock: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    photo: {
      data: Buffer,
      contentType: String,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

module.exports = Mongoose.model("Product", Product);
```

Category.js

```
const Mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = Mongoose.Schema;

const Category = Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
      unique: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

module.exports = Mongoose.model("Category", Category);
```

```
exports.getAllProducts = async (req, res) => {

  var products = await Product.find().populate("Category");

  return res.send(products);
};
```

I'm trying to get all products with it's categories in getAllProducts method
but it always return ObjectId in productType instead of category object. how can i get details from category collection?
what's wrong with this code?
why does populate is not working0?

Comment: try this `await Product.find().populate("productType");`, you have to specify field name that you have provided `ref` property. [refer](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: many many thanks bro. more than 50 examples i have seen in all that schema name and  model name both this is why i have got this confusion